# How many additional conditions can be assumed while proving a homogeneous Inequality?

Tags: inequality

I am learning how to prove Inequalities from the book: *Inequalities:Theorems, Techniques and Selected Problems.* In chapter $4$ the author says that if an inequality is homogeneous then we can assume additional conditions, which can reduce the inequality to a much simpler form. He calls this process as **Normalization**.

Now I read another article which claimed that only one condition can be assumed at a time. Moreover, I was wondering whether assuming that the variables have an order falls under the category of "additional conditions." So for instance if we are given to prove an inequality in three variables $a,b$ and $c$ with $abc=1$, can we assume WLOG that $a\geq b\geq c$?

Comment: Yes, If the original inequality is symmetric.

Comment: If symmetric you can assume this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Please define a symmetric Inequality.

Comment: @Shrey Aryan Which does not depend on all permutations of variables. For example $a+b+c\geq8$ is a symmetric inequality because $a+b+c=a+c+b=b+a+c=b+c+a=c+a+b=c+b+a$